# Disabling logging in 'transaction' package (Pyramid app)

Tags: python, transactions, pyramid, pylons

When debugging level of main logger in Pyramid app is set to `DEBUG`, `transaction` is spewing lots of pointless debug messages.

In Nosetests I can disable that this way:

```
from transaction._compat import get_thread_ident

txn_logger = logging.getLogger("txn.%d" % get_thread_ident())
txn_logger.setLevel(logging.WARN)
```

However, in Pyramid app the infrastructure adds "scoped session" to each HTTP request and that obviously means `get_thread_ident()` is different every time.

Is there some way of disabling that globally without repeating above in every single Pyramid view?

Comment: Shouldn't just using `"txn"` disable the child loggers as well?

Comment: And if that's the case, you could just add the logging configuration for that logger in your .ini config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply turn off logging for the `txn` parent logger in your logging config.

```
[loggers]
keys = transactions, ...

[logger_transactions]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = txn
```